# State of the art results for locating critical points in 2D classical vertex models or 1D quantum spin chains

Tags: critical-phenomena, simulations

I'm looking for benchmarks for my own method, but I could not find an answer so easily. I've found so far:

$\beta = 0.4407 \pm 0.0001$ for the 2D Ising model on a square lattice by Ghaemi, M., G. A. Parsafar, and M. Ashrafizaadeh. "Calculation of the critical temperature for 2-and 3-dimensional Ising models and for 2-dimensional Potts models using the transfer matrix method." The Journal of Physical Chemistry B 105.42 (2001): 10355-10359.